# Specifying maven project directory in exec tag

Tags: maven, gradle, ant, bamboo

I am running this in Bamboo using command task executable=Gradle.

```
<target name="deploy-jar">
<exec executable="${maven.bin}" >
<arg value="deploy:deploy-file" /> 
<arg value="-DgroupId=${groupid}" />
<arg value="-DartifactId=${artifact}" />  
<arg value="-Dversion=${version}" /> 
<arg value="-Dpackaging=jar" />
<arg value="-Dfile=${file}" />  
<arg value="-Durl=${maven.repo.url}"/> 
<arg value="-DrepositoryId=${maven.repo.id}" />
</exec>
</target>
```

The build is failing due to incorrect `executable="${maven.bin}"`

Would someone be able to give me the proper maven project location for it to run in Bamboo successfully? or at least an idea.

Thank you!!

Comment: Unless you've specified it explicitly with an environment variable such as `M2_HOME` there is really no magical solution to this (Maven is something that you unzip, not something you install, so that no entries of it are anywhere except on the disk, as far as I know).

Comment: @Andrei, thanks. my problem is I don't know the proper maven project location being used in Bamboo as I am building it in Bamboo with a project that runs on Ant.